# Passing Multiple Filter Values to API in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a function that takes in a user's filter selections and then sends out a request that filters the data returned according to those filter selections.

The problem I'm running into is that, even though I'm using conditional logic to determine what `type` a `value` is associated with, with my current implementation, because only one value can be retuned at a time, when a user makes a selection on the second filter (say, for location), the previous value (which, for instance, may have been for `language`) gets wiped out. In other words, I'm trying to figure out how to make sure I can stack filter selections - so that both language and location filter values will be passed to the API.

Perhaps I could make `language` and `location` properties inside an object? But then if I do that, how do I then pass those individual values to the API - which is expecting both "language" and "location" to be passed as individual params (which you can see in my last line of code below)? What would that look like?

This is what my function currently looks like:

```
private onFilterReceived(value: any, type: string, page)
{
    let language = '';
    let location = '';
    if (value && type === 'language')
    {
        language = value;
    }
    else if (value && type === 'location')
    {
        location = value;
    }

    let fn = resRecordsData => {
        this.records = resRecordsData;
        let data = resRecordsData.data;
    };

    this.filtersService.getByFilter(page - 1, this.pagesize, this.currentStage, language, location, fn);
}
```

Comment: Every time you call the onFilterReceived function, you reset language and location to an empty string, that's why it's wipeout. You need to store the value, so either use the scope of your component or create a service. I don't know how does your code look like, but I would probably have the language and location as a property of your component and update/delete them when you want.

Does it make any sense? I think I have a fever so I'm not exactly sure if I'm writing what I'm thinking.

Comment: The actual problem is that, say if I already have a value for "language", when I then make a "location" selection, my logic for language is no longer true - so the value for "language" is lost for that reason. The question is, how can I store the value for that variable? Pretty sure I can do it right here in the function. Just need a basic implementation example to get me started. Again, I think the problem is that with the current implementation, I can only return one value at a time. So it's currently always either one or the other -  I need to store and then pass both; maybe in an object?

Comment: Yeah, if you know all the filters when you call the function then you can have an object or array of objects as a parameter instead of value and type.